# Make Pinterest Profile Widget Secure

Tags: https, pinterest

I am using the below page to create a Pinterest Profile widget:
https://business.pinterest.com/en/widget-builder#do_embed_user

The problem is that when the widget displays the images use non secure links.  I need to display the widget on a secure page so need them to be https://

Any ideas how I can go about this?

Comment: Is your website `http://` or `https://`?

Comment: The entire site is https://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after a bit of research I have made a pretty intense hack to make this work. Pintrest does serve https content, it is just that for some reason they have not included this in their API. So I have stepped through the API and found the attribute setter that sets attributes to any elements the API creates.

Anyway.. here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nanff007/1/ (make sure to https)

And here is the code that performs the magic...

> This is a workaround/hack or whatever you want to call it. It will not work forever. It may also not work in all countries as the akamai urls may change. The best option would be to raise a request ticket with Pintrest.

```
(function() {
    $('a[data-pin-do]').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('data-pin-dont', $(this).attr('data-pin-do'));
        $(this).removeAttr('data-pin-do');
    });

    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        for (prop in window) {
            if (prop.search(/^PIN_/) > -1 && typeof window[prop] != 'boolean') {
                clearInterval(timer);
                window[prop].f.set = function (el, att, string) {
                    if(att == 'src' && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
                        string = string.replace(/(^http:\/\/)/i, "https://s-");
                    }

                    if (typeof el[att] === 'string') {
                        el[att] = string;
                    } else {
                        el.setAttribute(att, string);
                    }
                };

                $('a[data-pin-dont]').each(function () {
                    $(this).attr('data-pin-do', $(this).attr('data-pin-dont'));
                    $(this).removeAttr('data-pin-dont');
                });

                window[prop].f.init();
                break;
            }
        }
    }, 100);
}());
```

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like Pinterest broke this hack today or yesterday.

Comment: @KyleMacFarlane I just checked my jsfiddle and it seems to be working... what issue are you having?

Comment: I've been using your hack for months and it was working fine until today. However I did manage to fix it by clearing the cache in affected browsers. What would happen was the widget would fail to initialise and the console logged a bunch of 404s to "/https://log.pinterest.com" (notice the slash at the start). The question is are Pinterest just A/B testing or rolling out a new script?

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the https: and  start with  // as the beginning of the link. 
For Example:

< a href="//sub-domain.example.com">Acme Widgets

Remove the spaces before > and after < in the above example